# Suppose that 21 girls and 21 boys enter a math contest, Show that there is a question that was solved by at least three girls and at least three boys.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> Suppose that $21$ girls and $21$ boys enter a mathematics competition. Furthermore, suppose that each entrant solves at most $6$ questions, and for every boy-girl pair, there is at least $1$ question that they both solved. Show
>   that there is a question that was solved by at $3$ three girls and at leat $3$ boys.

My question is, why is the number $3$ special here, for example, I tried proving this question in the following way. Fix a girl $g$, this girl could've at most solved $6$ questions $q_1,\dots,q_6$. For the sake of contradiction, assume Each question was solved by at most 2 boys *or* at most two girls. We first consider if there is at most $2$ boys, then for each of the $6$ questions $g$ answered, there could be at most $2$ pairs involving her and $2$ other boys that solved this question, so for all her $6$ questions, there could be at most $12$ pairs that involve her and other boys. If we sum up this number over all $g$, ($21$ in total), we get the number of pairs is at most $21\times 6 \times 2=252$. This is a contradiction since there are $21^2=441$ pairs of boy-girls, the second case for at most $2$ girls also goes the same by symmetry, so in both cases we have a contradiction.

My question: Why is the number $3$ special here? If it would've been replaced by $4$, then our last equation would be $21 \times 6 \times 3=378$ which is still less than $441$, am I missing something here?

Comment: I think that you should prove that there exists a problem that was solved by at least 3 boys **AND** at least 3 girls, instead of trying to prove that there exists a problem solved by at least 3 boys **OR** at least 3 girls

Comment: @Stefan4024 Isn't the negation of there exists a problem that was solved by atleast 3 boys and atleast 3 girls, its negation is for all questions, at most 2 boys solved it OR at most 2 girls solved it, because I am proceding by contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, but your proof isn't alright. You proof that there exists a problem solved by at least 3 boys and a problem that is sovled by at least 3 girls. The thing that you haven't done is to prove that there exists a problem solved by at least 3 boys **AND** at least 3 girls.

For example what if we have a problem that is solved by $3$ boys and $2$ girls? You proof guarantees it's existence, but it doesn't help us at all, as it still satifies the negated condition, namely the second statement, which is enough as it's **OR** statement. The negated statement hasn't been contradicted yet.

Comment: I think he's trying to investigate that every question is solved either by less than 3 girls OR less than 3 boys - if that is falsified, then SOME question has to be solved by 3 or more girls AND 3 or more boys.

Comment: @stefan4024 - 'at most 2 boys or at most two girls' 3 boys and 2 girls does satisfy that condition - he's trying to prove that not all questions can fit into the condition - can you take 3/2 and fit them all into the condition space

Comment: Anyway, I think that it also works for > 3 - it's easy to show that the first boy has to pair at least one question with greater than 3 girls - then to keep going through the boys, the girls similarly seem to run out of answers

Comment: @AndrewDeighton It's true, but he hasn't proven it. Proving that there exists a problem solved by at least 3 boys doesn't contradict "at most 2 boys **OR** at most 2 girls has solved each problem", cause we don't have an information on the girls. We have only proved that the first part is wrong for some questions, but not both parts

Comment: @Stefan4024 I reread my proof and I think I wasn't very precise when writing it. Let me rephrase, Fix 1 boy $b$, At most, he answered 6 question. So Atleast 1 question of them has 3 or more girls that answered it, which means at most 5 questions of them had been answered by 2 girls or less. So atmost 5x2=10 pairs for questions with 2 girls or less involving $b$, or $21\times 10=210$ pairs with 2 girls or less. Similarly if we fix a girl $g$ and follow the same argument by symmetry, we get atmost 210 pairs with 2 boys or less answering a question. So total pairs is $210+210=420 < 441$.

Comment: @Stefan4024 - I know what you mean, because I was stuck at the same concept - however I thought he was arguing there was not enough questions to satisfy all the pairings  - I didn't fully understand it though.

Comment: @AspiringMat That's quite different from what you've written before. Using the things you've mentioned in the comment I've written a proof down, which I believe is more rigorous. Anyway as you might notice this proof fails to prove that there exist a problem solved by $4$ girls and $4$ boys. Actually I think one should be able to make a configuration without a problem solved by $4$ girls and $4$ boys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that there are at least $21^2 = 441$ connections between a boy and a girl. Let $S$ be the set of such connections ($|S| \ge 441$). Now color all the connections with different colours, depending on the problems. We can now write $S=A \cup B \cup C$, where  in the subset $A$ are the connections corresponding to problems solved by at most $2$ girls, in $B$ are the connections corresponding to a problem solved by at most $2$ boys and in $C$ are the connections corresponding to a problem solved by at least $3$ boys and at least $3$ girls. Note that each of connection must be in at least one of this sets and also let's note that $A$ and $B$ mustn't be disjoint. Obviously now our goal is to prove that $C \not = \emptyset$.

So now assume that $C = \emptyset$ and pick a random boy and as it has solved at most $6$ problems we have that there at least one of this problem has been solved by at least $3$ girls. So at most $5$ problems have been solved by at most $2$ girls. That means that each boy contributes to a $A$ by at most $5 \cdot 2 = 10$ connections. Therefore we have that $|A| \le 21 \cdot 10 = 210$. Similar reasoning gives us that $|B| \le 21 \cdot 10 = 210$.

So now:

$$|S| = |A \cup B \cup C| = |A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| \le 210 + 210 = 420$$

But this contradict the fact that $|S| \ge 441$, meaning that our assumption that $C = \emptyset$ is wrong. Therefore there is a connection in $C$ corresponding to a problem solved by at least $3$ boys and at least $3$ girls, guaranteeing the existence of such problem.

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution can be found in [this book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NWhIDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=21%20girls%2021%20girls%20problem%20solved%20by%20at%20most%206&source=bl&ots=URHyJ6yHLq&sig=cLbSr7B-cDqMDff2MGs4_zDqPQc&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE5OW4mvjPAhXEVRoKHdH9Ai4Q6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q=21%20girls%2021%20girls%20problem%20solved%20by%20at%20most%206&f=false). If you can't read all the book, you can refer to [this pdf](https://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/%7Erjaiswal/2013/csl105/Other/solution-tut-9.pdf) and [cut-the-knots](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pigeonhole/BoysGirlsProblems.shtml)

The idea is as follows: Start by making a $21\times 21$ matrix and assign to each problem a different letter. The entry $(i,j)$ consists of letters (problems) that girl $i$, and boy $j$ both solved.

**Observation 1**: In each row and in each column there will appear at most 6 distinct letters.

**Observation 2**: There will be at least 11 entries (squares) in each row,  that contains a letter that appears **at least 3 times** in that row. The same holds for every column.

Color the squares that contain a letter that appears at least 3 times in the same row red.

Color the squares that contain a letter that appear at least 3 times in the same column blue.

By a pidgeon hole argument you can show there is a square that is coloured both red and blue, which shows there is a problem that is solved by at least 3 girls, and 3 boys.

Since $21^2 < 21\times 11 + 21\times 11$ there must be a square that is both red and blue.

Edited:

The above 11 can be got from the above pdf link

> **at most 5** distinct questions such that for any such question there are **at most 2** girls who solved it

> This means that with the remaining
> 11 girls, this boy shares a problem that is solved by at least two other girls.

i.e. $11$ is got from $21-2*5$. This implies the basic idea of this answer is same as Stefan4024's.